# .data function in cuDF returning none

Tags: python, rapids, cudf

I am trying to make some operations using nvstrings but .data is returning None

```
import cudf
sents = 
cudf.read_csv("train.csv", 
quoting=3, skiprows=1, 
names=['review', 'label'])

gstr = sents['review'].data

print(gstr) -> None
```

dataset 
https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/av-blog-media/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/train.csv

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.13 nvstrings is deprecated where all of its functionality has been ported into libcudf into native string functions. You should be able to just use the `.str` accessor similar to Pandas and things should generally work as expected.

I.E. `sents['review'].str.lower()`